# How do I set test flags in an Android app to distinguish between running the app in test and production environments?

Tags: android, adb, android-debug

In the process of developing an Android app, I want to allow certain features if we're testing/debugging, and disallow the features when the app is in production. What's the best way to accomplish this? I've found some potential solutions in setting launch flags or setting intent flags when launching the main activity, but I don't know these will actually solve my problem, nor do I know the "best practices".

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do, but I would suggest taking a look at adding separate dev and prod product flavors: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors

Comment: This looks really promising -- thanks, @EricBachhuber!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty simple, as you want to set some feature available for debuge/test mode and some feature available for production app. You just have to use below code:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { 
      // do something for a debug build 
 } else {
      // do something for a Production app.
  }
```

Like this way you do not need to make different application for debug amd release app.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to create build variants, please review the documentation and examples, you'll probably see what you're looking for.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants

and

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html